# Installing module in python Annoconda "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install skdata module in Annoconda 2.2 verison
using

```
conda install skdata
```

But its throwing error as follows,

> Error: Package missing in current linux-32 channels: 
>     - skdata

Also its the same when I tried with

```
pip install skdata
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-ivxxkvsc/skdata/

I tried many solutions as

```
 python ez_setup.py
 pip install --upgrade setuptools 
 sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

None of these helping me to get rid of the error this error :Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

```
 python --version
Python 3.4.4 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (32-bit)
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: So it seems, no one has yet provided a (version matching) package with name `skdata`?

Comment: I wanted to use the tsne and skdata for visualizing my data in python platform..and So i found it can be via from skdata.mnist.views import OfficialImageClassification
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tsne import bh_sne

Comment: So that is the plan, than maybe you find hints on pages related to these packages starting from the vresions our master package (with the depends in it) needs if there is some other place  or a temporary built package to retrieve for your platform. That is my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not right now any `skdata` packages in the default conda channels or even on .

Pretty sure your the core issue is that `skdata` assume you're using python2, and you're trying to install in a python3 environment.

Try this:

```
conda create -y -n skdata-env python=2 scikit-learn pip
source activate skdata-env
pip install skdata
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and everytime I tried to launch Anaconda Navigator, it errored out. I tried everything but nothing seemed to work. Finally, when I was on the verge of giving up, I added the PATH to the pyqt5 and pyside folder and that did it for me. Everything got sorted, my package got installed and even Spyder started working. Took me 4 long days, but I finally got Anaconda and Spyder to work. Maybe you'll have some luck too.